# Nextjs getInitialProps blocked the page rendering in client side?

Tags: javascript, seo, next.js

Since I like to add SSR to my upcoming project to improve SEO, I would like to try out next. What I want is that only use SSR for the initial page, and the rest of navigations in the site will be client side rendering. I see the getInitialProps fit the most in this case, accordingly the documentations.

As my understanding, getInitialProps is run in server for the initial page rendering, and is run in the browser when navigating using next/link. The issue I found is that the getInitialProps seems to block the page rendering. (i.e. page changed/rendered after getInitialProps is completed)

```
import axios from 'axios'

function Posts(props) {
  return (
    <div>
      <div>Posts:</div>
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(props)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Posts.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  const response = await axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts');
  // Wait longer to see the effect
  // await (new Promise((resolve) => {
  //   setTimeout(resolve, 5000)
  // }))
  return {
    props: {
      posts: response.data
    }
  }
}

export default Posts;
```

**How can I do it like in pure React, render the jsx first, then fill in the props?** (the execution JSON.stringify(props) might be ignored at first)

Also, in next 9.3, the team introduced getServerSideProps, which is recommended over getInitialProps. How can they be comparable when they are not the same that getServerSideProps will on run in server?

Comment: The result of `getInitialProps` is passed to the page component as props. So next needs to wait for `getInitialProps` to resolve before rendering. Is that what you mean by "blocking"? If you want to do an initial render with dummy data or something, then just do normal react data fetching (e.g. useEffect).

Comment: Yes, it is what i mean bu blocking. I cannot do a csr because i will need to ssr in case of this page being the initial page. Is my idea even valid?

Comment: Were you able to resolve this? I am facing a similar issue.

Comment: @Vishu sorry for the late reply, I moved away from next. As I remember, it wasnt not What I expected. I am sure someone in the community will help u through. Good luck.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on your comments, you want to do the fetch on the server, on the initial page load. However, if navigating between pages you don't want rendering to block while waiting for `getInitialProps` to return.

One solution is to check if you're on the server, and do the fetch in `getInitialProps`. If on the client, don't do the fetch in `getInitialProps` and instead fetch using `useEffect` in your render method.

```js
import {useEffect} from 'react'
import axios from 'axios'

const isServer = () => typeof window === 'undefined'

const getPosts = () => {
  return axios.get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts')
    .then(response => response.data)
}

function Posts({posts}) {
  const [renderPosts, setRenderPosts] = useState(posts)

  useEffect(() => {
    if(posts === null) {
      getPosts()
        .then(setRenderPosts)
    }
  }, [])

  return (
    <div>
      <div>Posts:</div>
      <div>
        {JSON.stringify(renderPosts)}
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

Posts.getInitialProps = async (context) => {
  if(isServer()) {
    return {
      posts: await getPosts(),
    }
  }
  else {
    return {
      posts: null,
    }
  }
}

export default Posts
```

By the way, you may be tempted to use `getServerSideProps` here, since it is only called if rendering on the server. However, when a page using `getServerSideProps` is rendered, it will actually make a call to the server to get data from `getServerSideProps`, even if you're navigating using `next/link`. From the [Next.js 9.3 blog post](https://nextjs.org/blog/next-9-3):

> When navigating between pages using next/link instead of executing getServerSideProps in the browser Next.js will do a fetch to the server which will return the result of calling getServerSideProps.

This would still cause the blocking issue you're wanting to avoid.

One final note, this might not be an idiomatic solution. There may be a more "standard" solution. I just wasn't able to find one. You could likely also use a wrapper around your page component that could do all of this in a more consistent way. If you use this pattern a lot, I'd recommend that.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I feel like it is difficult to find next resource, as a new comer. Do you mean to do it in _app.js by wrapping the page component? And for the solution you provided looks great and will work. But there will still an extra round trip to the server, which I don't know if it is even a matter.

Comment: @Jerryc You have to talk to the server to get your data, there's no getting around that. There isn't an "extra" round trip. It's just the one call to get your data. That either happens when the server fetches the data and sends you the rendered page, including the data, on the initial page load. Or it happens when you navigate using `next/link` and it fetches directly from the API. In either case, you get one server call.

Comment: Sorry that i havent tried it out yet. As my inspection before. The client will always request for the page.json to the props. But not sure about a return of an empty object. If the getinitialprops hook does return an empty object and the client still requesting for json. Then It may be an extra round trip.

Comment: Thank you for ur time and explanation. I decided to go with pure react, since I believe google can react spa seo well.

Comment: @Cully i am facing a similar issue, moving api call to useEffect prevents render getting blocked. But can it affect SEO of my page doing it this way ?

Comment: @Vishu I have no idea how this affects SEO. However, on the initial page load, the posts will be fetched and rendered on the server. The `useEffect` code is just for navigations made after the initial page load. If you refresh the page, it will do the server-side render again. So it probably depends on how the bot works. If you don't want to use the `useEffect` method, just always fetch in `getInitialProps`. Or look into `getServerSideProps`.

Answer (score 0):

I implemented a solution different than @Cully.

I did not want to use getInitialProps as [it's considered legacy](https://nextjs.org/docs/pages/api-reference/functions/get-initial-props).

We can use this helper to know if we are on the first initial load, or after in a client navigation.

```
const isFirstServerCall = context.req?.url?.indexOf('/_next/data/') === -1;
```

So what I'm doing is :

Create a `ssr.ts` file like that :

```
import { DehydratedState } from '@tanstack/react-query';
import { GetServerSideProps } from 'next';

type ServerSideResponse = {
  dehydratedState?: DehydratedState;
};

export const onlyOnFirstServerCall = (
  getServerSidePropsFunc: GetServerSideProps<ServerSideResponse>
): GetServerSideProps<ServerSideResponse> => {
  return async (context: any) => {
    const isFirstServerCall = context.req?.url?.indexOf('/_next/data/') === -1;
    if (!isFirstServerCall) {
      return {
        props: {}
      };
    } else {
      return getServerSidePropsFunc(context);
    }
  };
};
```

And on your page, this function will be used like a HoC :

```
export const getServerSideProps = onlyOnFirstServerCall(async (ctx: any) => {
  const queryObject = ctx.query;
  ...what you do normally
});
```

So you have the choice to enable it or not.